# "Unable to determine aws-region" when running on-premises Cloudwatch agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to configure the AWS Cloudwatch agent to run on vanilla Ubuntu 18.04, outside of AWS. Every time I run it, I get this error:

```
# /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m onPremise -c "file:/path/to/cloudwatch/cloudwatch.json" -s
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-downloader --output-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --download-source file:/path/to/cloudwatch/cloudwatch.json --mode onPrem --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default
Got Home directory: /root
I! Set home dir Linux: /root
Unable to determine aws-region.
Please make sure the credentials and region set correctly on your hosts.
Refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
Fail to fetch the config!
```

Running the program under `strace -f` reveals that it is trying to read `/root/.aws/credentials` and then exiting. Per the guide, here are the contents of `/root/.aws/credentials`:

```
[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = secret
region = us-west-2
```

If I run `aws configure get region`, it is able to retrieve the region correctly. However, the Cloudwatch Agent is unable to read it. Here's the contents of `common-config.toml` (which also gets read, per strace).

```
## Configuration for shared credential.
## Default credential strategy will be used if it is absent here:
##  Instance role is used for EC2 case by default.
##  AmazonCloudWatchAgent profile is used for onPremise case by default.
[credentials]
   shared_credential_profile = "AmazonCloudWatchAgent"
   shared_credential_file = "/root/.aws/credentials"


## Configuration for proxy.
## System-wide environment-variable will be read if it is absent here.
## i.e. HTTP_PROXY/http_proxy; HTTPS_PROXY/https_proxy; NO_PROXY/no_proxy
## Note: system-wide environment-variable is not accessible when using ssm run-command.
## Absent in both here and environment-variable means no proxy will be used.
# [proxy]
#    http_proxy = "{http_url}"
#    https_proxy = "{https_url}"
#    no_proxy = "{domain}"
```

Here are other things I have tried:

- enclosing `region` (and all values) in the configuration in double quotes, per https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=291589. This did not make a difference.
- adding /home/myuser/.aws/config, /home/myuser/.aws/credentials, and /root/.aws/config and populating them with the appropriate values. Per strace these files are not being read.
- searching for the source code for the CloudWatch Agent (it is not open source)
- setting AWS_REGION=us-west-2 explicitly in the program environment (same error)
- changing `[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]` to `[profile AmazonCloudWatchAgent]` everywhere and all permutations of the above (no difference)
- adding a `[default]` section in all config files (makes no difference)
- invoking the `config-downloader` program directly, setting AWS_REGION etc. (same error)
- becoming a non-root user and then invoking the program using `sudo` instead of invoking the program as the root user without `sudo`.

I get the same error no matter what I try. I installed the CloudWatch agent by downloading the "latest" deb on March 23, 2020, per these instructions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html

Comment: Side-question: Are you replacing `-c "file:/path/to/cloudwatch/cloudwatch.json"` with a correct value? (Don't know if it will help, but that does look odd.)

Comment: yes, I'm replacing it with a valid value.

Comment: do you have a /root/.aws/config file with [profile AmazonCloudWatchAgent]
region = eu-west-1 (or your region)? This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an incorrect "secret" with an invalid character that caused the INI file parser to break. The CloudWatch agent incorrectly reported this as a "missing region," when a parse error or "invalid secret" error would have been more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

The aws config defaults to C:\Users\Administrator instead of the user you installed the CloudWatch Agent as. So you may need to move the /.aws/ folder to the CLoudWatch user. Or...more straightforward:

```
aws configure --profile AmazonCloudWatchAgent
```

as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html#install-CloudWatch-Agent-iam_user-first

You can also specify the region using `common-config.toml` as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html#CloudWatch-Agent-profile-instance-first

> On a server running Windows Server, this file is in the C:\ProgramData\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent directory. The default common-config.toml is as follows:

```
# This common-config is used to configure items used for both ssm and cloudwatch access


## Configuration for shared credential.
## Default credential strategy will be used if it is absent here:
##            Instance role is used for EC2 case by default.
##            AmazonCloudWatchAgent profile is used for onPremise case by default.
# [credentials]
#    shared_credential_profile = "{profile_name}"
#    shared_credential_file= "{file_name}"

## Configuration for proxy.
## System-wide environment-variable will be read if it is absent here.
## i.e. HTTP_PROXY/http_proxy; HTTPS_PROXY/https_proxy; NO_PROXY/no_proxy
## Note: system-wide environment-variable is not accessible when using ssm run-command.
## Absent in both here and environment-variable means no proxy will be used.
# [proxy]
#    http_proxy = "{http_url}"
#    https_proxy = "{https_url}"
#    no_proxy = "{domain}"
```

You can also update the common-config.toml with a new location if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new file in the same folder as **credentials** with the name **config**

And add there the region

```
[default]
region = your-region
```

[see more here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment the `# [credentials]` in the `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml` config file as well

Answer (score 0):

Set the AWS_REGION environment variable.

On Linux, macOS, or Unix, use :
export AWS_REGION=your_aws_region